# Как открыть и записать из бинарного файла массив?

Tags: c++

вот я имею задание:
Для двух файлов А та В, которые включают в себя по 17 элементов:
A = {ai}, B = {bi}, i =1,17 необходимо выполнить следующие действия с элементами аi и bi :
сi= (ai/bi)- и записать полученные значения ci в файл c = {ci}.

Я написал код для текстового файла, но не знаю как писать для бинарного, есть ли большие различия при записи и чтении бинарного файла и можно ли обойтись без массива и записать последовательность чисел в файл без него?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include<fstream>
#include<Windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    int a[17] = {};
    int b[17] = {};
    int c[17] = {};
    fstream f;
    fstream f2;
    fstream f3;
    f.open("LR3(1).txt", fstream::in | fstream::out);
    f2.open("LR3(2).txt", fstream::in | fstream::out);
    f3.open("LR3(3).txt", fstream::in | fstream::out);
    if (!f) {
        cout << "Ошибка открытия файла";
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Файл 1 открыт\n";
    }
    if (!f2) {
        cout << "Ошибка открытия файла";
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Файл 2 открыт\n";

    }
    if (!f3) {
        cout << "Ошибка открытия файла";
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Файл 3 открыт\n";

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
        a[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;
        f << a[i] << " ";
        b[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
        f2 << b[i] << " ";
        c[i] = (a[i] / b[i]) - 2;
        f3 << c[i] << " ";
    }
    f << endl;
    f2 << endl;
    f3 << endl;
    cout << "Массив в 1 файле:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
        f >> a[i];
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Массив в 2 файле:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
        f2 >> b[i];
        cout << b[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Массив в 3 файле:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
        f3 >> c[i];
        cout << c[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    f.close();
    f2.close();
    f3.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Можно и без массива, только зачем? элементов меньше 10к значит проще сразу всё считать.

Comment: Это для себя, пробую что-то новое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для работы с бинарными файлами, нужно сначала установить режим `binary` у потоков `fstream`

```
fstream f;
fstream f2;
fstream f3;
f.open("LR3(1).bin", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::binary);
f2.open("LR3(2).bin", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::binary);
f3.open("LR3(3).bin", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::binary);
```

А далее пример вашего кода без использования массива, с комментариями:

```
//Генерируем переменной случайное значение
//после чего записываем его в бинарный файл
int a, b, c;
for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
    a = rand() % 100 + 1;
    //Конвертируем переменную в массив байтов грубо говоря
    //и записываем sizeof(int) байт в файл
    f.write((char*)&a, sizeof(int));
    b = rand() % 100 + 1;
    f2.write((char*)&b, sizeof(int));
    c = (a / b) - 2;
    f3.write((char*)&c, sizeof(int));
}

//Устанавливаем указатели get в файлах на начало файлов
f.seekg(0);
f2.seekg(0);
f3.seekg(0);

//Считываем по тому же принципе, как и записываем
cout << "Массив в 1 файле:\n";
for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
    f.read((char*)&a, sizeof(int));
    cout << a << " ";
}
cout << endl;
cout << "Массив в 2 файле:\n";
for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
    f2.read((char*)&b, sizeof(int));
    cout << b << " ";
}
cout << endl;
cout << "Массив в 3 файле:\n";
for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
    f3.read((char*)&c, sizeof(int));
    cout << c << " ";
}
cout << endl;

f.close();
f2.close();
f3.close();
```

Как вы видите, для работы с бинарными файлами используются две функции `write` и `read`, которые принимают первым параметром буффер откуда будет браться информация или куда будут она будет записываться, а вторым параметром функции принимаю размер считываемой или записываемой информации.

Так же есть функции `seekg` и `seekp` они перемещают указатели `get pointer` или `put pointer` на число байт `offset` от установленного `origin`. В вашем случае используется `seekg` чтобы установить указатель для чтения, на начало файла.

Поподробней про работу с бинарными файлами можете почитать [тут](http://ci-plus-plus-snachala.ru/?p=86), поподробней об `seekp` и `seekg` [тут](http://www.c-cpp.ru/books/proizvolnyy-dostup)

Comment: спасибо, все понял)

Comment: да, конечно могу